# fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102] on linux MySql database

Tags: mysql, linux, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core, ubuntu-18.04

I am using the Entity Framework Core ORM v3.1.3 to manage a MySql database. Trying to deploy an Angular ASP.NET app on a linux Ubuntu 18 server and encountering the following error. This error only occurs in deployment on linux and NOT when published on my windows machine which uses MySql version 8.0.18.

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
      An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'dynamify.Models.MyContext'.
      MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY `a`.`admin_id` ORDER BY `a`.`admin_id`) AS `row`
              FROM `Adm' at line 6
       ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY `a`.`admin_id` ORDER BY `a`.`admin_id`) AS `row`
              FROM `Adm' at line 6
         at MySqlConnector.Core.ResultSet.ReadResultSetHeaderAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ResultSet.cs:line 49
         at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.ActivateResultSet() in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlDataReader.cs:line 130
         at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.CreateAsync(CommandListPosition commandListPosition, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, IDictionary`2 cachedProcedures, IMySqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlDataReader.cs:line 391
         at MySqlConnector.Core.CommandExecutor.ExecuteReaderAsync(IReadOnlyList`1 commands, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\CommandExecutor.cs:line 62
         at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlCommand.cs:line 217
         at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(DbContext _, Boolean result)
         at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
```

The error goes on to detail how Entity parsed the SQL:

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (4ms) [Parameters=[@__site_id_parameter_1='?' (DbType = Int32), @__site_id_parameter_2='?' (DbType = Int32), @__site_id_parameter_3='?' (DbType = Int32), @__site_id_parameter_4='?' (DbType = Int32), @__site_id_parameter_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT `s`.`title`, `s`.`active`, `s`.`admin_id`, `t0`.`admin_id`, `t0`.`first_name`, `t0`.`last_name`, `t0`.`email`, `t0`.`password`, `t0`.`c`, `s`.`site_id`, `t1`.`paragraph_box_id`, `t1`.`title`, `t1`.`priority`, `t1`.`content`, `t1`.`site_id`, `t2`.`image_id`, `t2`.`title`, `t2`.`priority`, `t2`.`image_src`, `t2`.`site_id`, `t3`.`portrait_id`, `t3`.`title`, `t3`.`priority`, `t3`.`image_src`, `t3`.`content`, `t3`.`site_id`, `t5`.`two_column_box_id`, `t5`.`title`, `t5`.`priority`, `t5`.`heading_one`, `t5`.`heading_two`, `t5`.`content_one`, `t5`.`content_two`, `t5`.`site_id`, `l`.`title`, `l`.`priority`, `l`.`site_id`, `l`.`link_box_id`, `l`.`type`, `l`.`content`, `l`.`url`, `l`.`link_display`, `n`.`site_id`, `n`.`string_of_links`, `n`.`nav_bar_id`
      FROM `Sites` AS `s`
      LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT `t`.`admin_id`, `t`.`first_name`, `t`.`last_name`, `t`.`email`, `t`.`password`, `t`.`c`
          FROM (
              SELECT `a`.`admin_id`, `a`.`first_name`, `a`.`last_name`, `a`.`email`, `a`.`password`, 1 AS `c`, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY `a`.`admin_id` ORDER BY `a`.`admin_id`) AS `row`
              FROM `Admins` AS `a`
          ) AS `t`
          WHERE `t`.`row` <= 1
      ) AS `t0` ON `s`.`admin_id` = `t0`.`admin_id`
      LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT `p`.`paragraph_box_id`, `p`.`title`, `p`.`priority`, `p`.`content`, `p`.`site_id`
          FROM `ParagraphBoxes` AS `p`
          WHERE `p`.`site_id` = @__site_id_parameter_1
      ) AS `t1` ON `s`.`site_id` = `t1`.`site_id`
      LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT `i`.`image_id`, `i`.`title`, `i`.`priority`, `i`.`image_src`, `i`.`site_id`
          FROM `Images` AS `i`
          WHERE `i`.`site_id` = @__site_id_parameter_2
      ) AS `t2` ON `s`.`site_id` = `t2`.`site_id`
      LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT `p0`.`portrait_id`, `p0`.`title`, `p0`.`priority`, `p0`.`image_src`, `p0`.`content`, `p0`.`site_id`
          FROM `Portraits` AS `p0`
          WHERE `p0`.`site_id` = @__site_id_parameter_3
      ) AS `t3` ON `s`.`site_id` = `t3`.`site_id`
      LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT `t4`.`two_column_box_id`, `t4`.`title`, `t4`.`priority`, `t4`.`heading_one`, `t4`.`heading_two`, `t4`.`content_one`, `t4`.`content_two`, `t4`.`site_id`
          FROM `TwoColumnBoxes` AS `t4`
          WHERE `t4`.`site_id` = @__site_id_parameter_4
      ) AS `t5` ON `s`.`site_id` = `t5`.`site_id`
      LEFT JOIN `LinkBoxes` AS `l` ON (`s`.`site_id` = `l`.`site_id`) AND (`s`.`site_id` = `l`.`site_id`)
      LEFT JOIN `NavBars` AS `n` ON `s`.`site_id` = `n`.`site_id`
      WHERE `s`.`site_id` = @__site_id_parameter_0
      ORDER BY `s`.`site_id`, `t1`.`paragraph_box_id`, `t2`.`image_id`, `t3`.`portrait_id`, `t5`.`two_column_box_id`, `l`.`link_box_id`, `n`.`nav_bar_id`
```

Here is the query I wrote in C# that triggers the error:

```
List<Site> FoundSites = dbContext.Sites.Where(x => x.site_id == site_id_parameter).Select( site => new Site()
            {
                site_id = site_id_parameter,
                title = site.title,
                active = site.active,
                admin_id = site.admin_id,
                owner = dbContext.Admins.Where(x => x.admin_id == site.admin_id).Select(s => new Admin()
                {
                    admin_id = s.admin_id,
                    first_name = s.first_name,
                    last_name = s.last_name,
                    email = s.email,
                    password = s.password
                }).FirstOrDefault(),
                paragraph_boxes = dbContext.ParagraphBoxes.Where(x => x.site_id == site.site_id).Select(box => new ParagraphBox()
                {
                    paragraph_box_id = box.paragraph_box_id,
                    title = box.title,
                    priority = box.priority,
                    content = box.content,
                    site_id = box.site_id
                }).Where(x => x.site_id == site_id_parameter).ToList(),
                images = dbContext.Images.Where(x => x.site_id == site.site_id).Select(i => new Image()
                {
                    image_id = i.image_id,
                    title = i.title,
                    priority = i.priority,
                    image_src = i.image_src,
                    site_id = i.site_id
                }).Where(x => x.site_id == site_id_parameter).ToList(),

                portraits = dbContext.Portraits.Where(x => x.site_id == site.site_id).Select(p => new Portrait()
                {
                    portrait_id = p.portrait_id,
                    title = p.title,
                    priority = p.priority,
                    image_src = p.image_src,
                    content = p.content,
                    site_id = p.site_id
                }).Where(x => x.site_id == site_id_parameter).ToList(),

                two_column_boxes = dbContext.TwoColumnBoxes.Where(x => x.site_id == site.site_id).Select(tcb => new TwoColumnBox()
                {
                    two_column_box_id = tcb.two_column_box_id,
                    title = tcb.title,
                    priority = tcb.priority,
                    heading_one = tcb.heading_one,
                    heading_two = tcb.heading_two,
                    content_one = tcb.content_one,
                    content_two = tcb.content_two,
                    site_id = tcb.site_id
                }).Where(x => x.site_id == site_id_parameter).ToList(),
                link_boxes = dbContext.LinkBoxes.Where(x => x.site_id == site.site_id).Select(lb => new LinkBox()
                {
                    title = lb.title,
                    priority = lb.priority,
                    site_id = lb.site_id,
                    link_box_id = lb.link_box_id,
                    type = lb.type,
                    content = lb.content,
                    url = lb.url,
                    link_display = lb.link_display
                }).Where(x => x.site_id == site.site_id).ToList(),

                nav_bars = dbContext.NavBars.Where(x => x.site_id == site.site_id).Select(nb => new NavBar(){
                    site_id = nb.site_id,
                    string_of_links = nb.string_of_links

                }).ToList()
            }).ToList();
```

I have remade the linux instance and managed to re-create the issue. A friend of mine also deployed the app code base and was able to reproduce the error as well.

MySql was installed on linux using the command:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Any feedback on this issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution to this. At the time of this posting, the command:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

installs MySQL version 5.7 by default. This version of MySQL will not work with the newer features in Entity Framework. If you want to use Entity Framework v3.1 +, you should install MySQL 8 on your linux server.

[This Article](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-mysql-8-0-on-ubuntu-linux/) Gave me clear directions for how to install MySql on Ubuntu 18